# Semi Colon Issue in JS

Tags: javascript, minify

I happened to come across the following weird case:

One of the network calls returned a response like this:

```
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
} window.project = 'test';
```

But when the following script is getting evaluated, it is returning an error

> Unexpected Identifier

This issue gets fixed when a `semi-colon` is added after the function1 definition So the correct fix is:

```
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
}; window.project = 'test';
```

I am curious to know the reason behind this.

Comment: The semi-colon behind the closing brace of function1 specifies that its an anonymous function. Its the syntax of jQuery using which anonymous functions are being written.

Comment: Simply You're trying to write two instruction in a single line.If you put `window.project = 'test';` in new line, we don't need `;` after curly brackets but I prefers the semicolon and single instruction per single line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
} window.project = 'test';
```

js engine reads this entire thing as one statement ,since it can't find any semicolon for the anonymous function assignment, it continues parsing only to find  `window.project = 'test` and so it gives you an error.

```
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
}; window.project = 'test';
```

here because you have a semicolon after the anonymous function, js engine can figure out that that these are 2 different statements.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the semicolon can be omitted if the statement is followed by a line break.

Here you have 2 statements in the same line, so the first semicolon is obligatory.

But you could write something like:

```
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
}; window.project = 'test'
```

(without the last semicolon)

More details here: https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/507f6dd09266b70200000d7e

Answer (score 0):

`function1` is a variable, which does not appear to be concluded before `window.project` ; `js` interpreting both variables as `function1`. Could add a comma `,` operator following `function1` declaration to avoid syntax error between the two variables `function1`, `project`

```js
window.function1 = function() {
  console.log('function 1');
}, window.project = 'test';
```